# Remove Firefox custom search from bookmark

Tags: firefox, search, bookmarks

I created a custom search using a bookmark. [I followed these directions.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar) I no longer want the search.

I deleted the bookmark, but it didn't remove the search. When I use the keyword it uses the custom search instead of the default search engine.

I am using Firefox version 105.0.1 on POP!_OS 22.04

EDIT: Adding more details on request.

Firefox allows you to add custom searches. I set `lol` as a custom keyword for searching https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki. I decided I no longer wanted `lol` to be a custom search so I deleted it in the firefox menu. However, when I entered text that began with `lol` it still searched the wiki. This happened despite the custom search being deleted from the firefox preferences gui.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue: *removed custom searches from bookmarks still appeared in the search bar*. Although, I think it is related to Firefox Sync in my case (I've removed the bookmark on one machine successfully, but on another machine keyword still triggered the search).

What helped me to remove the keyword search is:

1. Add bookmark again with "Add a Keyword for this Search..." with the same keyword
2. Remove it from bookmarks

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a database editor. I used [sqlitebrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org).
2. Go to `~/.mozilla/firefox/"profile folder"/places.sqlite`
3. Delete the record from `places.sqlite` in the "moz_keywords" table.
4. Save changes

Make sure the browser is closed when you do this.

If you aren't sure your profile folder's name, open firefox and in the address bar enter "about:profiles". If you still can't figure out which profile it is, try the default one.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a search engine:

- Click the menu button and select Settings
- Click on Search in the left pane
- Under "Search Shortcuts", click on the search engine you want to remove
- Click the "Remove" button below the list to remove it.

Comment: In my case, the search engine was not listed there, but the keyword still triggered the search.